# Simple search in Spring MVC

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, model-view-controller, crud

I'm new to Spring MVC, and I'm trying to do a simple search.
Here's my Controller and View. How do I make the search to actually work?
 The findTeamByName is already implemented from a interface and the Teams are already populated in memory.
Thank you in advance guys!

```
@Controller
public class SearchController {

  @Autowired    
  SuperPlayerService sp;

  @RequestMapping(value="/search")
    public ModelAndView Search(@RequestParam(value = "searchTerm", required = false) 
    String pSearchTerm, HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {
        ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView("search");

       mav.addObject("searchTerm", pSearchTerm);
       mav.addObject("searchResult", sp.findTeamByName(pSearchTerm));      

     return mav;
   }
}
```

JSP:

```
<%@ page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8" %>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="t" tagdir="/WEB-INF/tags" %>
<%@ taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" prefix="form" %>


<t:MasterTag>
<jsp:attribute name="pageTitle"><c:out value="Search"/></jsp:attribute>
<jsp:attribute name="currentMenuName"><c:out value="Search"/></jsp:attribute>
<jsp:body>





<div class="row">
     <div class="small-3 columns">
        <input type="text" id="txt" name="searchString">
      </div>

       <div class="small-5 columns end">
         <button id="button-id" type="submit">Search Teams</button>
       </div>

   </div>

 <div class="row">
      <div>
         ${searchTerm}
     </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

you can return your values i.e in a `ModelAndView`

```
@RequestMapping(value="/search/{searchTerm}")
public ModelAndView Search(@PathVariable("searchTerm") String pSearchTerm) {
    ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView("search");

    mav.addObject("searchTerm", pSearchTerm);
    mav.addObject("searchResult", sp.findTeamByName(pSearchTerm));      

    return mav;
}
```

This field can be accessed in your search.jsp by `${searchTerm}`

**EDIT:**

if you want so search like: `search?searchTerm=java` then you can do it with:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/search")
public ModelAndView Search(@RequestParam(value = "searchTerm", required = false) String pSearchTerm, HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {
    ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView("search");

    mav.addObject("searchTerm", pSearchTerm);
    mav.addObject("searchResult", sp.findTeamByName(pSearchTerm));      

    return mav;
}
```

Comment: I did as you adviced chresse and I get 404 error when trying to accesss http://localhost:8080/aplication-web/search.

Comment: yes. You have to access /search/java ie to search for "java".

Comment: I tried as you said and I got 
HTTP Status 500 - Request processing failed; nested exception is com.application.exception.DelegatedResultException: no team found named null !  when I tried to access search?searchTerm=SRM

Comment: ahh sry. I updated the code (added HttpServletRequest and HttpServletResponse)

Comment: Ok chreese :) I can access it now but it shows my entire object.
How do I pass the url search into my search field in order not to need to use the url. Sorry for the noob questions

Comment: I updated my code. The way it is, when I try to hit my URL "application/search" I get HTTP Status 400 - Required String parameter 'searchString' is not present

Comment: I am sorry, but i don't know what you mean. If you mean how your form has to look like, it has to be a simple form, with GET method and a field named `searchTerm` which sends the request to `/search`

Answer (score 3):

Spring MVC Controller method can accept a wide range of arguments and one of them is org.springframework.ui.Model.

You can add values to the Model which will become available in your JSP at requestScope.

In your case, your Java code would look like this

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/search")
public String Search(@RequestParam("searchString") String searchString, Model model) {

    if(searchString != null){
        Object searchResult = sp.findTeamByName(searchString);
        model.addAttribute("searchResult", searchResult);  
    }

    return "search";
}
```

In your JSP, you could then access the result as usual object in requestScope like ${searchResult}

Comment: Javakid, this gives me HTTP Status 400 - Required String parameter 'searchString' is not present :( The jsp file gets like this?
 
     <div>
        ${player.superTeam}
    </div>

Comment: Ok. It looks like your search string is not coming through under parameter name searchString. In your JSP <input> tag, I see you have both id and name. Try to remove one of them and see what happens.

Comment: I updated my code, but I'm still getting HTTP Status 400 - Required String parameter 'searchString' is not present

Answer (score 2):

Your JSP needs to look like:

```
<%@ page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8" %>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="t" tagdir="/WEB-INF/tags" %>


<t:MasterTag>
<jsp:attribute name="pageTitle"><c:out value="Search"/></jsp:attribute>
<jsp:attribute name="currentMenuName"><c:out value="Search"/></jsp:attribute>
<jsp:body>

<div></div> 

<div class="row">
    <form method="get" action="/search">
       <div class="small-3 columns">
          <input type="text" id ="txt" name="searchString" >
       </div>

       <div class="small-5 columns end">
          <button id="button-id" type="submit">Search Teams</button>
       </div>

       <div>
           ${player.superTeam}
       </div>
    </form>

</div>
```

And your controller would be:

```
@Controller
public class SearchController {

   @Autowired    
   SuperPlayerService sp;


   @RequestMapping(value = "/search")
   public String Search(@RequestParam("searchString") String searchString) {

      if(searchString != null){
         sp.findTeamByName(searchString);
      }

       return "search";
   }
}
```